# DateTime class not found, even when adding backslash

Tags: php

I'm trying to use DateTime to measure the time it takes for a part of a program to run.

My code is in the namespace 'App'.
From my understanding, DateTime is in the global namespace, so it has to be prefixed with a blacklash. Which I've done, but I'm still getting an error that DateTime class can't be found.

```
$startTime= new \DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
//other code in here
$endTime = new \DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$timeTaken = date_diff($startTime, $endTime)->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
 Class 'App\DateTime' not found
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Comment: Show full code, where is the namespace `app` defined?

Comment: And did you test it in a online-php-tester? There you need `\\\`

Comment: Only to be right: __That code you show here, works fine__ no errors.

Comment: May be you have `new DateTime();` anywhere in your code

Comment: could it be that you are using a very old PHP version?

Answer (score 0):

in the begining of you php file add

```
use DateTime;
```

In your code

```
$startTime= new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
```